# Edit ListView Items and save changes

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-listview

Firstly, I'm an absolute beginner in Android. I'm trying to create a ListView that shows items from an Array of Strings and allow the user to edit these items by just clicking in which one he wants to modify. These changes must be saved in the array of strings too. 
Here's my code (important pieces) and classes:

MainActivity.java (send through Intent the array saved statically (preSetDevices))

```
String preSetDevices [] = {"D4:92:9D:F5:1C:1A","E5:05:65:5E:C4:E7","ED:3E:77:06:9E:46"};

...
        btsetDevices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setDevices);
        btsetDevices.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetDevices.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("array_set_devices", preSetDevices);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
```

SetDevices.Java (receive the intent, show the item in the ListView (here's where I want to modify the item and save these changes on array of strings)

```
public class SetDevices extends Activity{

ListView lvResult;
Intent intent;
String[] array_devices_received;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_devices);
    registerClickCallBack();

     intent = getIntent();
     array_devices_received = intent.getStringArrayExtra("array_set_devices");

     lvResult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvResult);

         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_devices_received);         
        lvResult.setAdapter(adapter); }

        private void registerClickCallBack() {
            lvResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) {

//What do I have to put here to edit items of the listview and save changes in this array of string, (I will return this array modified to  MainActivity.java through Intent again later)

                }
            });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be much more easier and efficient to use an `ArrayList` and not a simple array.

In your `SetDevices` class, use this example code method to import your simple array into an ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<String> arrayToArrayList(String[] array){
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(array.length);
    for(String string : array){
        arrayList.add(string);
    }

    return arrayList;
}
```

Then you set the `ArrayList` in your adapter and take use of it's methods to update/edit/remove items from your ListView.

Good luck!